How to obtain pairing of flights that minimises layover time away from home?
Now, here is a hypothetical Airline crew assignment problem. An airline that operates seven days a week has a time table shown below. Crews must have a minimum layover of 7.5 hours between flights. Obtain the pairing of flights that minimizes layover time away from home. For any given pairing, the crew will be based on the city that results in the smaller layover. In  the following time-table SFO stands for San-Francisco city in United states of America  and DEN stands for Denver city in United states of America.

For each pair,also mention the town where the crew should be based.
My difficulties: 1) I didn't understand the term'Layover'. 2) 'Obtain the pairing of flights that minimises layover time away from home' means what?
In a nutshell, please explain me this problem in all  of its details.

"Layover" means the amount of time between arrival of the first flight and departure of the next flight.  The idea is to find four (roundtrip) pairs of flights, where for each pair one flight is in $\{1,2,3,4\}$ and one flight is in $\{101,102,103,104\}$.  For each such pair, both layovers must be at least $7.5$ hours.  The problem is to minimize the sum (over the four pairs) of the longer of the two layovers.

Here Airline crews can be based in San Francisco or in Denver. Let's say a crew is based in San Francisco. They take the flight no. $\color{red}1$ to Denver. They arrive the airport at 9:30 AM. The crew can take the flight no. $\color{red}{102}$ from Denver back to their home airport in San Francisco. The stay time in Denver would be the difference between 11:00 AM and 9:30 AM, which is one and a half hours. But this is not long the enough, since it is smaller than $7.5$ hours. So we add $24$ hours. Therefore the $\textbf{layover time}$ for a San Francisco team which take the flights $1$ and $102$ is $25.5$ hours or $1530$ minutes.
You can make a table in that manner for a San Francisco team and a Denver team. Then take for each combination of flights the minimum of the two values. This is the matrix where you start from.
Now you assign a flight with the numbers $1,2,3,4$ to exactly one flight with the numbers $101$ to $104$ by minimizing the layover times. Such a assignment problem can be solved with the Hungarian method.

Flight number 1 SFO-DEN departure time from SFO airport is 7.00 AM and  arrival time at DEN airport 9.30 AM.  Flight number 101 DEN-SFO departure time from DEN airport is 9.30 AM and arrival time at SFO airport is 12.00 Noon.  Is my this understanding of time table correct?

Yes, it is correct.
